# How to remove ads/talking from an audio file

Tags: audio, script

I have a server setup to record an hour of audio everyday from a radio stations mix they have daily. Unfortunately there are some ads in it and it's a bit tedious to manually remove them all the time, especially since that's an hour of daily content, sometimes even 2 hours depending on the day.

I'd like to remove this just for my personal use.

I know many DVR's have this feature for TV shows, I wonder if such is true for audio as well. My googling has turned up blank. I have found some people who remove based on set times, however the ad break times vary so I cannot use that.

Comment: Internet radio or simple radio? The waveform is linear b/w a song and an ads. Choose those and remove them with [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/).

Comment: @Biswa Internet radio being streamed that I am then recording to an mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will more than likely have to manually remove the ads.  You are only capturing raw audio, so there is no metadata that could possibly used to assist you.

Comment: Well it is from a radiostation and on their site they also provide the name of the artist and such so many I can use metadata? And the audio has a difference compared to the music in the waveform.